# How to print a long string into a table separated by #

Tags: vb.net

I have a long string of three words at the end of each one there #
Is all stored in a text file
How to print it until the # 
in the file: Jorj# bush# 123456# the president of USA#
i want sonthing like:

```
Dim details() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
Dim query = From line In details
            Let fullname = line.Split("#"C)(0)
            Let family_name = line.Split("#"c)(1)
            Let phone_number = line.Split("#"c)(2)
            Let comment = line.Split("#"c)(3)   
            Select fullname, family_name, phone_number, comment
```

Comment: I need something like... what does not work in the query apart from the wrong names (it should be `Select fullname, family_name, phone_number, comment`)?

Comment: look for my example now.....

Comment: very wired i try it now after save and its work....

Comment: seems a little ineffcient to split `line` 4 times but ...

Answer (score 2):

That should work as expected. But you could make it more efficient:

```
Dim query = From line In details
            Let parts = line.Split("#"c)
            Let fullname = parts(0)
            Let family_name = parts(1)
            Let phone_number = parts(2)
            Let comment = parts(3)
            Select fullname, family_name, phone_number, comment
```

Otherwise you're splitting every line 4 times.

Comment: That's better, and whilst I don't like it (for some unfounded reason), any other ideas I have end up with something less straightforward. +1